# TinyMCE: can't write special chars on mac after focus change

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, tinymce, ascii

I have this problems on some macs. When the editor loads it's possible to type all kind of chars. But: After making focus in other textfield (flash) in the page and comming back to the editor, is not possible to write special chars anymore.

With special chars I mean like äöüáóíÄÖÜß ("extended" ASCII). Other chars are possible (ASCII - before 127).

Any hint is greatly appreciated. If you have a good idea how to debug this or some hint to investigate, which leads me to the response, it's also accepted.

The only thing I made is put a console.log in a key listener of TinyMCE, in the source. To see if at least the key press is being detected. And it is - the console lists all key presses. But the characters don't appear on screen.

The console output didn't show any errors or warnings before / when this problem appears.

What could it be? Maybe it's not TinyMCE's fault at all? As far I saw in the code, the key presses are only processed for some backspace - undo etc. tasks, but the actual typing goes through the browser ? -> iframe with body contenteditable="true".

Another information which is maybe useful: The other textfield I'm talking about is inside a Flash application. The focus in this field makes that is not possible to write special chars in TinyMCE anymore. Maybe the field changes the charset or something from the webpage or system..? How can I see / investigate this?

Comment: this is definetly not tinymce's fault, but looks more like an OS/browser problem, maybe even flash issue

Comment: I tested the console output in a keylistener of TinyMCE and it detects all key presses. So they are fired at least and "arrive". But nothing appear in the editor :(

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  After uploading a file with Plupload, and then inserting the URL via execInstanceCommand(..., "mceInsertCommand"), I can't type any characters at all (not just special).  But backspace works.   On my Mac, this only affects Chrome, but not Safari or FF

Comment: This sounds very similar http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77172 but supposedly it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

a workaround could be to catch those events and treat them in the mac OS case:

```
ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'\uFFFF'); // FFFF stands for the special character coding
```

Comment: That's a very good idea, didn't think about that. But the problem is that I have it only in some macs (didn't find relation to browser or OS version yet) and I don't know what's the cause. Well, I could prevent event forwarding of special chars for all macs, and insert like you are saying. That way I don't have doubles in the macs where it works. Will test.

Comment: Not working, the editor detects keydown for these chars, but not keypress (for some reason the keypress of special chars go to flash!). And only with keypress it's possible to get the correct charCode (ASCII). Keycode is not enough to get correct ASCII as far I know. Anyways +1 for almost helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but not quite the same.  So this may or may not help you.

In my case, after the user uploads a file with the Plupload library (by clicking the invisible Flash button) and then the event handler inserts an URL into TinyMCE via `execCommand("mceInsertCommand", ...)`, the user can no longer type any characters at all (more than just the special characters would be affected).  However, the backspace key would still work.

On my Mac, this problem only affected Chrome, but not Safari or FF.

My workaround was to hide the flash object temporarily, give the editor focus via `editor.focus()`, and use an underscore `defer` call to re-show the flash object.